# "Unexpected End of data" error while implementing tensorflow translate

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I was implementing the code of `models/rnn/translate/translate.py`.
The code I am using is the same as given in [this link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.py), but it gives an error.

```
ReadError: unexpected end of data

Traceback (most recent call)
    buf = self.fileobj.read(size)
    749         if len(buf) != size:
--> 750             raise ReadError("unexpected end of data")
    751         return buf
```

I am not sure how to proceed. Please help with this error.

Comment: That looks like it might be a problem with the file reading, so it's worth double checking that the file's present and loading correctly. We'll also need to see more of your code to be able to help you figure out what's going wrong, since it's not part of the original translate.py script.

Comment: @Pete Warden I am trying to run exact "Translate.Py"

Comment: In that case, can you give the complete error logs? My confusion was because the translate.py script only has 279 lines, and your error is shown on line 750. I'm guessing that the error must be occurring in a file that the translate.py script is calling in that case?

Comment: Actually line 750 is from the traceback of error . There is no  750th line in code . Main code is copy of translate.Py

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue today and could not find the reason why there is this offset that makes it crash. However here's a work around if you still want to run the script `translate.py`:

- Download and extract the training set in `/tmp`: http://www.statmt.org/wmt10/training-giga-fren.tar (_WMT_ENFR_TRAIN_URL)
- In `data_utils.py`, comment the [two lines of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkQnM.png) in `get_wmt_enfr_train_set` that are responsible for the extraction.

If you get a similar issue for the dev set just proceed in the same way with the url denoted by _WMT_ENFR_DEV_URL.